# Redis - I see only 10 values in DB

Tags: configuration, server, redis, key, limit

I need help about redis server. I have redis and I have a problem with number of keys in DB. I configured redis, but I can't to have more keys than 10 in my Redis server. Why?

```
port 6379
dir /var/lib/redis/
dbfilename dump.rdb
protected-mode yes
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 300
tcp-keepalive 0
loglevel notice
databases 16
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
slave-serve-stale-data yes
slave-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
slave-priority 100
appendonly no
maxmemory 10GB
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

Can you help me, with the configuration?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Install Redis Desktop Manager and cross check that how many keys are present in redis.

Comment: Redis has no real limit on the number of keys. How do you know the number of keys in your DB - have you run `DBSIZE` or `INFO keyspace`?